# Make a numeric dictionary in notepad++?

Tags: notepad++, dictionary, nppscript

I want To create a numeric dictionary on **notepad++**.
Starting from `1` to `100000`.
Like with lines:

```
1 || 1
2 || 2
3 || 3
```

I tried using loops.
Maybe there is a code like: `{{LOOOP!}}`. Which we can use while loops.
Any help please.
If you want more information, then feel free to comment.

Comment: Do you use NppScripts for this?

Comment: @Nifle Yeah....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't know if you need to use NppScripts for this, but if you simply want to create a text file in the format you listed you could use simple cmd line code.

`(for /L %n in (1,1,100000) DO @ECHO %n ^|^| %n) > Output.txt`

You can copy and paste this into a command prompt and it will create a text file named Output.txt with lines `1 || 1` to `100000 || 100000` in the current directory (can take a few seconds to run).

Comment: You are a genius.

Comment: Using It makes my computer super slow but its okay.

Comment: Got it working in NppScripts if you are interested, has some minor quirks.